# $n$ points on a circle

Tags: combinatorics

Choose $n$ points on a circle so that no three of the $\binom{n}{2}$ chords have a common point inside the circle. Let $a_{n}$ be the number of regions formed inside the circle by drawing the cords.

Obtain the recurrence relatin $a_{n}=a_{n-1}+f(n)$ for $n\geq 1$ where $f(n)=n-1+\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}(i-1)(n-1-i)$.

It is clear where the $a_{n-1}$ comes from and the $n-1$ in $f(n)$ but what does this product mean? We have $(i-1)(n-1-i)$ extra regions for each $i$? And what would the $i$ be indexing? The points on the circle? Any hints on this problem would be nice. I've been stumped for a few days now.

Comment: It's not so clear to me what aspect you're having trouble understanding, and on what level. Are you unfamiliar with summations? Are you having trouble understanding the intuitiv meaning of that summation? Are you having trouble proving the recurrence?

Comment: Is this supposed to be maximum number of regions, because according to the setup I can create chords that don't intersect at all, in which case the number of regions is simply $n+1$.

Comment: @Sachin_ruk No, you can't. If $n=4$ then $2$ of the $6$ chords **will** intersect.

Comment: @Sachin_ruk You need consider _all_ chords connecting any two points you have marked.

Comment: @dfeuer I'm having problems proving the recurrence.

Comment: I don't know about the recurrence, but the closed formula $a_n=\binom{n}4+\binom{n}2+1$ can easily be derived using Euler's formula $V+F=E+2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fix the $n$th point that you introduced. The chords which do not involve this point will yield $a_{n-1} $ regions.

How many regions are introduced by adding chords involving the $n$th point?

**Hint:** The number of regions is equal to the number of points of intersection of each chord with the remanding chord, plus 1.

**Hint:** If we connect it to the point that is $i$ vertices away, then chords intersect it if one of the endpoints is the $i$ vertices, and another of the endpoints is the other $n-1 - i$ vertices.

Do you see how to arrive at $f(n)$ now?

Comment: I don't see where the extra 1 comes from in the first hint. I think it should just be the number of intersections.

Comment: @TheNumber23 Draw some pictures, it will help. The important thing isn't the number of intersections, but the number of line segments. There is 1 more line segment than the number of intersections, since if there are 0 intersections, there is 1 line segment.

Comment: Oh ok that makes sense.